# How to change proxy settings with authentication?

Tags: password, proxy, authentication

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and having WiFi connection with proxy settings and authentication.

By following some tutorials I successfully changed `/etc/apt/apt.conf` with the values

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:p@sswd@192.168.0.0:800/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://username:p@sswd@192.168.0.0:800/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:p@sswd@192.168.0.0:800/";
Acquire::socks::proxy "socks://username:p@sswd@192.168.0.0:800/";
```

The problem is my password contains "@" character and I have tried everything to make it work,

1. I tried `http://username:p\@sswd@192.168.0.0:800/` [escape character]
2. I tried `http://username:p%40sswd@192.168.0.0:800/` [replacing with HTML-ised hex code]
3. I tried `http://username:p%40sswd%40192.168.0.0:800/` [same to the other @ also]
4. I tried `http://username:p@sswd%40192.168.0.0:800/` [same to the other @ only]
5. I tried `http://username:p\%40sswd@192.168.0.0:800/` [escaping % character]

but none of the above worked. Please suggest me some way to make it work.

Comment: (2) is the correct way. Do you get a `407 Authentication required` error or something else?